# Script to replace string of text at a end of a line

Tags: scripting, powershell-4.0

I would like to modify this script if possible:

```
((Get-Content -path "C:\Users\User1\OUT\Summary.txt" -Raw) -replace '</ab></cb>','</x>') | Set-Content -Path "C:\Users\User1\OUT\Summary.txt"
```

I would like a script that will run with Windows OS to search through one file it finds at this path:

```
C:\Users\User1\File\Summary.txt
```

And within that file, when it finds data starting with: `<a><b>Data`

And at the same time ending with: `</ab></cb>`

It would need to change the ending to: `</x>`
And it would need to save the file without changing the name of the file.

For instance a line showing this data:

```
<a><b>Data:</y> 12345678</ab></cb>
```

Would be changed to:

```
<a><b>Data:</y> 12345678</x>
```

The PowerShell script above will find all instances of `</ab></cb>` and replace it with `</x>`, which is not what I am hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-Content` to process the file line be line and only do the `Replace` when you have a `Match` on `<a><b>`. Something like this:

```
$InFile = ".\TestIn.txt"
$OutFile = ".\TestOut.txt"
If (Test-Path -Path $OutFile) {Remove-Item $OutFile}

Get-Content $InFile | ForEach-Object -Process {
  $NewLine = $_
  If ($_ -Match '<a><b>') {
    $NewLine = ($_ -Replace '</ab></cb>','</x>')
    }
  Add-Content $OutFile $NewLine
}
```